# How do I move a Linux software RAID to a new machine?

Tags: linux, software-raid, gentoo, mdadm, raid5

I have a newly built machine with a fresh Gentoo Linux install and a software RAID 5 array from another machine (4 IDE disks connected to off-board PCI controllers). I've successfully moved the controllers to the new machine; the drives are detected by the kernel; and I've used mdadm --examine  and verified that the single RAID partition is detected, clean, and even in the "right" order (hde1 == drive 0, hdg1 == drive 1, etc).

What I don't have access to is the original configuration files from the older machine. How should I proceed to reactivate this array without losing the data?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You really kinda need the original mdadm.conf file.  But, as you don't have it, you'll have to recreate it. First, before doing anything, [read up on mdadm via its manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm).  Why chance losing your data to a situation or command that you didn't have a grasp on?

That being said, **this advice is at your own risk.  You can easily lose all your data with the wrong commands.  Before you run anything, [double-check the ramifications of the command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm).  I cannot be held responsible for data loss or other issues related to any actions you take - so *double check everything*.**

You can try this:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose /dev/md{number} /dev/{disk1} /dev/{disk2} /dev/{disk3} /dev/{disk4}
```

This should give you some info to start working with, along with the ID.  It will also create a new array device /dev/md{number}, from there you should be able to find any mounts.  **Do not use the `--auto` option, the man page verbiage implies that under certain circumstances this may cause an overwrite of your array settings on the drives.**  This is probably *not* the case, and the page probably needs to be re-written for clarity, but why chance it?

If the array assembles correctly and everything is "normal", **be sure to get your mdadm.conf written and stored in `/etc`, so you'll have it at boot time.**  Include the new ID from the array in the file to help it along.

Comment: +1 - Right on! I've moved several RAID-1 and RAID-5 sets around between Linux machines. One thing I'm not sure about is where you're seeing the info about "--auto". From the manual page on a CentOS 5.1 machine, I'm only seeing tht "--auto" creates a /dev/mdX entry (or entries) for the array. I'm not seeing anything that might indicate that it would write to the drives. (In fact, "--auto=yes" is the default in the mdadm on CentoS 5.1 if "--auto" is not specified.) "--update" can be your friend if you need to move an array to a different mdX number from the orginal specified in the superblock.

Comment: Excellent, I can successfully mount the array. The only lingering issue is that the RAID doesn't come up after a reboot; I have to rerun mdadm -Av /dev/md0. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you recreate the /etc/mdadm.conf file?  The system will look in this file at boot time to find arrays.

Comment: I did. What made the difference was recompiling the kernel with CONFIG_MD_AUTO. I hadn't initially because I thought there was a way mdadm would do it instead. I read sonewhere that the kernel code isn't as robust as using mdadm to automount, but I can't find anything to back that up anymore.

Comment: If you do have the mdadm.conf file see if you can also find the old fstab file. From both take the lines that are about the old array and copy paste those lines in their corresponding files. I did this when I re-used an array from another server and after 2 reboots it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add my full answer for Debian at least.

- Install the raid manager via --> 
  `sudo apt-get install mdadm`
- Scan for the old raid disks via --> 
  `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`
- At this point, I like to check `BLKID` and mount the raid manually to confirm.

  `blkid
  mount /dev/md0 /mnt`
- Append Info to mdadm.conf via --> 
  `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
- Update initramfs via --> 
  `update-initramfs -u`
- Troubleshooting:

Make sure the output of `mdadm --detail --scan` matches your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

```
    nano /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

    ARRAY /dev/md/0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=00.90 UUID=a44a52e4:0211e47f:f15bce44:817d167c
```

- Example FSTAB

  ```
  /dev/md0    /mnt/mdadm   ext4    defaults,nobootwait,nofail     0    2
  ```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/using-mdadm-examine-to-write-mdadm-conf/52935#52935

https://askubuntu.com/questions/729370/can-i-transfer-my-mdadm-software-raid-to-a-new-system-in-case-of-hardware-failur

[How do I move a Linux software RAID to a new machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32709/how-do-i-move-a-linux-software-raid-to-a-new-machine)

Answer (score 2):

An issue with a 4 disk data Raid0 separate from the OS disk when updating the OS from CentOS 6.2 to CentOS 8.2 brought me here.

I was able to get use Avery's accepted answer above (https://serverfault.com/a/32721/551746), but ran into problems due to Raid Layout confusion introduced in Kernel 3.14.

Following this post (https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/debx7w/mdadm_raid0_default_layout/) I had to change the default layout (/sys/module/raid0/parameters/default_layout) in order for the new Kernel to use the old Raid0 layout.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/mdx
echo 2> /sys/module/raid0/parameters/default_layout #study the previous link to see if 2,1 or 0 needs to be echoed here.
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

If that works, add the kernel parameter so the raid0 default layout is 2 (or 1 or 0) on reboot by editing /etc/default/grub and setting

```
raid0.default_layout=2
```

Rebuild grub.cfg, add to /etc/fstab and reboot!

Answer (score 1):

```
mdadm -Ac partitions -m 0 /dev/md0
```

Scan all partitions and devices listed in /proc/partitions and assemble /dev/md0 out of all such devices with a RAID superblock with a minor number of 0.

if the conf was successful you can add --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf so it catches it on boot

Answer (score 0):

**2023 UPDATE**

Things are easier now, and this more-or-less works without any messing around, or manual assembly, or access to the original config, and so on. The procedure below was tested on a move of a 10-year-old 3-drive RAID 5 setup from SL (ie. RedHat) 6.9 to Ubuntu 22.04.

If you can, get the following from the old machine:

1. `mdadm.conf` (`/etc/mdadm.conf` or `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`)
2. `/etc/fstab`
3. The output from `cat /proc/mdstat`
4. The output from `mdadm -D /dev/mdx`, where 'mdx' can be found from (3) (ie. `/dev/md0`)

It doesn't really matter if you can't get this information; you just need it for a sanity check.

Now install `mdadm` on the new machine, and reboot. There will be a new `mdadm.conf` (almost certainly in `/etc/mdadm`), which should correctly report the drive UUID (it should be the same UUID as the one reported by `mdadm -D` on the old machine). This will look something like

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.1 UUID=68d1ea02:83b09989:707c6320:1905a656 name=0
```

The new output from `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm -D` should be pretty much identical to the output from the old machine, except that the device is likely to have changed (in my case, `/dev/md127` changed to `/dev/md0`) and the sizes reported may be slightly different.

You now need to create an `/etc/fstab` entry, and you (preferably) need an fstab-style UUID for this (this is *not* the same UUID as the one reported by `mdadm`). If your new array is `/dev/md0`, then

```
  $ blkid | grep /dev/md0
 /dev/md0: UUID="some-long-uuid" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

Now create the directory where you want to mount the new drive, and create an `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
UUID=some-long-uuid  /data   ext4   defaults   0 2
```

In this case, the array will be mounted at `/data`.

Test the new fstab entry by running `mount -a` as root; this will mount anything which has not yet been mounted. You should also check `/etc/mtab` to confirm that the mount options are correct:

```
$ cat /etc/mtab | grep /dev/md0
/dev/md0 /data ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=256 0 0
```

Don't try to reboot before running these tests. If you get the UUID incorrect, the kernel will boot to an emergency console with a dependency error. To recover, remove your new `/etc/fstab` entry and reboot.

After a reboot you should see the old array at the mount point.